# Spark StackOverflowError thrown

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

My spark application receives from Kafka topic an `InputMessage`. That message contains a session id (that i filter in the first `mapWithState` function) and a topology name (that i filter based upon Zookeeper configuration and save it in the second `mapWithState`). After this I'm trying to save the topology name to database but after some minutes the app is throwing an exception.

```
JavaPairInputDStream<byte[], byte[]> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, byte[].class, byte[].class,
                    DefaultDecoder.class, DefaultDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);

            JavaDStream<InputMessage> inputMessageStream = directKafkaStream.map(avroRecord -> InputMessageTranslator.decodeAvro(avroRecord._2))
                    .filter(f -> f != null && f.getSessionID() != null && f.getDataName() != null);
            inputMessageStream.checkpoint(Durations.seconds(2));
            // LOGGER.info("Processing {} messages", inputMessageStream.count());

            // JavaDStream<InputMessage> transformed into JavaPairDStream with InputMessageKey as Key and InputMessage as value
            JavaPairDStream<InputMessageKey, InputMessage> pairInputMessageStream = inputMessageStream
                    .mapToPair(w -> new Tuple2<InputMessageKey, InputMessage>(new InputMessageKey(w.getSessionID(), w.getDataName()), w));
            pairInputMessageStream.checkpoint(Durations.seconds(2));

            // Function for keeping the state of the message received from kafka and how to handle duplicate messages.
            Function3<InputMessageKey, Optional<InputMessage>, State<Integer>, Tuple2<InputMessageKey, InputMessage>> mappingFunction = (key,
                    value, state) -> {
                if (state.exists()) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    state.update(1);
                    return new Tuple2<InputMessageKey, InputMessage>(key, value.get());
                }
            };

            Function3<String, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, String> mappingFunctionTopology = (key, value, state) -> {
                if (state.exists()) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    state.update(1);
                    return key;
                }
            };

            // Stream data is saved in a mapWithState and is deleted after a configured time
            JavaMapWithStateDStream<InputMessageKey, InputMessage, Integer, Tuple2<InputMessageKey, InputMessage>> stateDStream = pairInputMessageStream
                    .mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunction)
                            .timeout(Durations.minutes(new Integer(startProps.getProperty(InputPropertyKey.TIMEOUT.toString())))));
            stateDStream.checkpoint(Durations.seconds(2));

            JavaDStream<Tuple2<InputMessageKey, InputMessage>> mapWithStateDistinctAndFiltered = stateDStream
                    .transform(rdd -> rdd.distinct().filter(r -> r != null));
            mapWithStateDistinctAndFiltered.checkpoint(Durations.seconds(2));

            JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> topologyNameStream = mapWithStateDistinctAndFiltered.mapToPair(f -> {
                String topologyName = f._2.getDataName();
                if (ZookeeperConfigurationReader.topologyNameExists(topologyName, "localhost:2181", "/Topologies")) {
                    return new Tuple2<>(topologyName, 1);
                }
                return null;
            }).filter(f -> f != null);

            topologyNameStream.checkpoint(Durations.seconds(2));
            JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, Integer, Integer, String> mappedTopologyNameStream = topologyNameStream
                    .mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunctionTopology));

            mappedTopologyNameStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
                rdd.foreachPartition(p -> {
                    TopologyRestClient rest = new TopologyRestClient("http://localhost:8080/topology");
                    p.forEachRemaining(r -> {
                        rest.createObject(r);
                    });
                });
            });
```

It's throwing

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1512)
```

It fails at `distinct()` ..... according to yarn ui....

Thank you!